# Converting an array of numbers in an array of strings to a two dimensional float array in python

Tags: python, arrays

So, I have a set of xml extracted data that is in the form of a list. Within the list is a array of six values. I would like to convert that list to a two dimensional array of floats. For example I would like to convert:

```
a = ['1 2 3 4 5 6', '6 5 4 3 2 1', ...]
```

to:

```
a = [[1 2 3 4 5 6],
     [6 5 4 3 2 1],
     ...          ]
```

Thanks for taking a look at this

Comment: `b = [list(map(float, x.split())) for x in a]`

Comment: By "two dimensional array", do you mean a list of lists, or a 2D numpy array, or something different?

Comment: Also, if you do mean a numpy array, how big is it? Is it small enough that you can afford to build a list of lists to build the array from, or so big that you have to build it iteratively?

Comment: There are no arrays in your example, only `list` objects, which don't have dimensions (but can be arbitrarily nested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to `split` each string, convert the split numbers into floats, and gather them up.

---

If you're asking about building a list of lists, this is simple:

```
a = [[float(number) for number in s.split()] for s in a]
```

---

If you want to build a 2D numpy array, the easiest way to do it is to build it from a list of lists:

```
a = np.array([[float(number) for number in s.split()] for s in a])
```

---

If your list is huge, so you can't afford to build that intermediate list of lists and have to do it iteratively, the best way is usually [`fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html):

```
rows = len(a)
cols = len(a[0].split())
it = (float(number) for s in a for number in s.split())
a = np.fromiter(it, dtype=float, count=rows*cols)
a = a.reshape(rows, cols)
```

And you can of course collapse that down into a horrible one-liner if you really want to:

```
a = np.fromiter((float(number) for s in a for number in s.split()), dtype=float, count=len(a)*len(a[0].split())).reshape(len(a), len(a[0].split()))
```

---

Another option is to loop and fill in the array:

```
rows = len(a)
cols = len(a[0].split())
b = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=float)
for i, row in enumerate(a):
    b[i] = [float(number) for number in row.split()]
a = b
```

This is basically equivalent to the `fromiter` solution. There may be a minor performance difference one way or the other, but likely the more important difference is which one makes more sense to you.